# Angularjs directive: Passing a model reference to an isolated scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I 'm trying to write a collapsible, reusable  calculator directive, that binds to an input field (in the parent scope). This input field itself has a `ngModel` binding. 
When the user presses the equals-button of my directive this parent scope model should be updated. I need to isolate the scope so I can reuse it:

Here is the simplified code and how I would like to use it: 
http://plnkr.co/edit/OSOcxydJWh8K520nstAU?p=preview

I tried passing in the values as an attribute. but that does not work because I don't know how to update this attribute inside of the controller(I tried the `$attrs` service).

So how can I update the model from the directive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you're overthinking it, maybe I'm underthinking it. Either way, here's all I did to change yours to make it work:

```
if ($scope.operator ==='+') {
  $scope.field = parseInt($scope.field) + $scope.operand;
}
```

I uncommented your scope and then I made sure that your controller made reference to the data you had exposed in your scope. That's it.

And here's a working version of your Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/btBi3E

Comment: thanks, that is exactly how I wanted to use it. What I tried was accessing it like an injected serivce ( console.log(field), instead of console.log($scope.field)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `ngModelController`. Here's a link with docs, with a handy example:
[NgModelController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController)